# readWithCallback function not working in swift 3

Tags: swift, callback, swift2, swift3

Before the swift update(in swift 2) my code was like the following and it worked successfully with no errors.

```
     client.me.events.readWithCallback({
          (list: Array<AnyObject>!, error: MSOrcError!) -> Void in
     }
```

But after the swift update (in Swift 3) I get errors in the previous code, so I changed it to the below code. It has no errors but when I run the app it gets crashes and terminates. When I remove the last line I get an error saying:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Any?' to expected argument type
>   '(([Any]?, MSOrcError?) -> Void)!'

```
      client.me.events.read(callback: Any?{
          (list: Array<AnyObject>!, error: MSOrcError!) -> Void in
     } as! (([Any]?, MSOrcError?) -> Void)! )
```

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that the *expected argument type* is `(([Any]?, MSOrcError?) -> Void)!`. Why don't you follow it?

```
    client.me.events.read(callback:  {(list: [Any]?, error: MSOrcError?) in
        //...
    })
```

Or simply:

```
    client.me.events.read {list, error in
        //...
    }
```